# FIOS Quantum Router Guest Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Can someone explain how the Guest Wi-Fi network works on the FIOS Quantum router? Is it a separate channel in addition to the normal (dual-band) 2.4 and 5 GHz channels? Or, does it commandeer one of the bands leaving only one available for normal, full-network access, Wi-Fi? Are there performance penalties to the normal Wi-Fi connections for having Guest Wi-Fi enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a separate channel. It uses the same 2.4 or 5GHz radio.  Your guest users and your "regular" users will compete for the same bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, I see that now with my WiFi sniffer app. The 2.4 GHz radio is running two SSIDs on the same channel. Thanks for the reply.